# Complete Function Before Remote Operation in NgRx

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ionic5

I'm having an issue with a race condition in NgRx. In the example below, I'm asynchronously presenting a loading dialog at about the same time as I'm starting an async remote operation. But the remote operation has the potential to complete and fire dismissLoadingDialog() before the loading dialog is fully built, which results in a console error.

What might be a good strategy in NgRx to complete presentLoadingDialog() before the remote operation begins?

```
@Effect() fetchServerData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<FetchServerData>(ActionTypes.FetchServerData),
    switchMap(action => {
      this.presentLoadingDialog('...loading');
      return this.dataService.fetchData(action.payload).pipe(
        map(result => {
          this.dismissLoadingDialog();            
          return new FetchServerDataSuccess(result);
        }),
        catchError(err => of(new FetchServerDataFail(err)))
      );
    })
  );


async presentLoadingDialog(message: string): Promise<void> {
    this.isLoading = true;
    return this.loadingCtrl
      .create({
        duration: 5000,
        message: message
      })
      .then(loadingDialog => {
        loadingDialog.present().then(() => {
          if (!this.isLoading) {
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
          }
        });
      });
  }

  async dismissLoadingDialog() {
    this.isLoading = false;
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(this.loadingCtrl)): Promise<boolean> {
      return this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I created a simple state library called ez-state, take a look at it's usage here with loading spinners if you are interested. Much easier than ngrx. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8t3cqc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic's LoadingController `create` method returns a Promise which resolves when loader creation is complete. You can therefore use it in your effect's Observable chain:

```js
presentLoadingDialog(message: string) {
  const loader = this.loadingCtrl
    .create({
      duration: 5000,
      message: message
    });
  return loader.present();
}

dismissLoadingDialog() {
  this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
}

@Effect() fetchServerData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<FetchServerData>(ActionTypes.FetchServerData),
  switchMap(action => forkJoin(from(this.presentLoadingDialog('...loading'), of(action)),
  switchMap(([_, action]) => this.dataService.fetchData(action.payload).pipe(
    tap(() => this.dismissLoadingDialog()),
    map(result => new FetchServerDataSuccess(result)),
    catchError(err => {
      this.dismissLoadingDialog();
      return of(new FetchServerDataFail(err))
    })
  ))
);
```

Comment: Hey Will, thanks for the tip, I think this is what I'm looking for. Could you complete the chain when you get a chance? I'm still trying to process Rxjs operators and can't quite figure out how my fetchData() observable fits in there. I'll award you the bounty afterwards.

Comment: Looks like it is working! I just had a couple modifications: I changed my presentLoadingDialog method to return a Subject so I removed the from() operator, and then I believe there's a parenthesis missing from the forkJoin, so the forkJoin line ended up looking like the comment below:

Comment: switchMap(action => forkJoin(this.presentLoadingDialog('...loading'), of(action))),

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The standard I have seen is you have loading and loaded flags in your state. When you dispatch a load action the reducer updates the state with loading: true and loaded: false before the action fires the http request. The action then switch maps to an action that updates the state with the response and loading: false and loaded: true.

In your component you then have a selector for the loading flag and subscribe to it to open and close the dialog

```
this.loadingSub = loadings$.subscribe(loading => {
  if (loading) {
    this.presentLoadingDialog('...loading');
  } else {
    this.loadingDialog.dismiss();
  }
});
```

unsubscribe in onDestroy

It should be up to your components to show UI components, I think actions calling loading dialogs is not an action concern. Tapping into the heart of state management to call UI components is not a pattern I would recommend.

Comment: In a traditional angular app I would agree with this, but we're using Ionic 5 which uses  native loading dialogs which must be fired from the .ts file. I could write a custom component to show/hide instead, but it seems like I should be able to insert the loading dialog observable into the stream.

Comment: But the store should not know about UI concerns, you could listen to the loading$ observable and fire the dialog in the component. I would definately reject an pull request that was using UI components in the store. The store makes observables emit, end of story in my option, it should not have any UI knowledge at all.

Comment: I have edited the question to call your dialog functions in the component rather that the store.

Comment: This is an old pattern, and one that is not recommended.